# Induction strategy with mathematical symbols

Tags: induction

The induction principle  is used to prove a sequence of propositions $P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3, ...$.

And it proceeds as follows

(i)  Verify $P_0$.
(ii) Assuming truth of $P_k$ for some $k$, verify $P_{k+1}$.

In this way, denoting by $S$ the set of those $k$ for which $P_k$ is true, then $S$ verifies both (i) and (ii) in the induction principle. Hence S coincides with N, so all propositions $P_k$ are true.

Can one describe this using mathematical symbolisms rather than prose ?  What does one do exactly ?

Comment: You can replace everything with notation but it often makes it harder to read and solve. Introducing notation requires justification.

Comment: In second order logic, it can be written as an axiom about sets of natural numbers. In first order logic, you are stuck with an "axiom schema." That is, an infinite collections of axioms that follow a pattern.

Comment: There is a reason that we use function-like notation rather than sequence notation, $P(n)$ rather than $P_n.$ $P(n)$ has a particular meta-meaning in first order logic.

Comment: First order logic, second order logic,  Not heard about that.  Is there anything good to read of it?

Comment: Is there a symbol in mathematical logic that specifies truth of a proposition P ?

Comment: Typically the truth of proposition $P$ is represented by $P$ itself. So induction can be written as something like $((P_0 \land \forall k (P_k \implies P_{k+1})) \implies \forall n P_n$.

Comment: I like the expression.  As something that I had in mind would look like.